# Thread interleaving scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to get my head around some interleavings and am playing around with some code. I have the following code

```
volatile int num;

First thread:
num = 10;
num = num + 5; 

Second thread:
num = 20;
num = num - 1;
```

Would I be right in saying that there would be 24 possible interleavings (possible orders of execution sequences) of the code if both threads concurrently run. Also, would there only be two possibilities if `num` is no longer volatile and both threads run while holding the same lock?

Answer (score 1):

Without any locking, all interleavings are possible. So:

```
a: num = 10;
b: num + 5; 
c: num = b

d: num = 20;
e: num - 1;
f: num = e
```

In all executions, abc and def are ordered, so:

```
abcdef
abdcef
adbcef
dabcef
dabecf
daebcf
deabcf
deabfc
deafbc
defabc
```

If you use a lock enclosing (abc) and (def), then:

```
abcdef
defabc
```

Comment: That is a beautifully succinct answer.

Comment: Why can you not have b running before a and d running before c?

Comment: According to the Java memory model, every thread observes modifications in the order they happen, but other threads may see those out of order. When you use `volatile`, all threads will see the modifications in the order they happen. Thus, b always happens after a, and d always happens after c.

Comment: The b and d are not atomic.

Comment: @akuzminykh, you're right. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Now b and e are not atomic. ;) E.g. in b reading `num` and adding `5` are two operations. However, as `5` is constant, it doesn't matter anyways. The c and f are also not atomic as e.g. reading b and assigning to `num` are two operations. However, it doesn't matter too because b is constant at the time it's used in c.

Comment: @akuzminykh, for the purposes of this question, b and e are atomic, because it only involves reading `num`. Once that's done, adding a constant will not affect the result. c and f are atomic in the sense that other threads will neither observe the temporary result nor can they affect it. So it is only a write to a volatile.